# <option selected="selected"> text </option> returns always a value despite having no value

Tags: php, html, jquery, html-select

My problem is option value which is
 `<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select a city...</option>`
The problem is : despite this option having no value, php code sees its value as *** 'Select a city'***. So, my code `if(isset($_POST['city'])` returns always true even a city is not choosed. How can I solve this?

Here is **html** code :

```
<form id="city_form">

  <select id="city" name="city">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select a city...</option>
    <option value=1 name="city1">City 1</option>
    <option value=2 name="city2">City 2</option>
    <option value=3 name="city3">City 3</option>
    <option value=4 name="city4">City 4</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit form" id="submit_button" />

</form>
<div id="show_city"></div>
```

Here is **jquery** codes :

```
$('#submit_button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $('#city_form').serialize();
  $.post(
         "fetch_city.php",
          data,
          function (response) {
             $('#show_city').html(response);
          }
        );
});
```

Here is **fetch_city.php** :

```
if (isset($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['city'])) {

  $city_id = $_POST['city']);
  echo $city_id;

} else {
  echo "You did not select a city...!";
}
```

Comment: fyi `!empty` implies `isset` so you do not `isset` if you test for `!empty`

Comment: And $city_id = (int) $_POST['city']) won't be useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Give it a meaningful sentinel `value` and ignore the control if that value comes up.

```
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Select a city...</option>
```

Comment: The reason for this is because if an option has no `value` attribute, the text inside it is used as the `value` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer here is jquery ignores the disabled on the first option. Try removing both the selected="selected" and disabled="disabled" from this. You'll now see a blank first entry. When the form is submitted your isset should return false.